# how to make material2 tabs to use full page size

Tags: css, angular, tabs, flexbox, angular-material2

I want to create tab group having two tabs. Tab group should use the full page size and the individual tab should get equal width. Following is code that I am using

```
<md-tab-group fxFlexFill>
    <md-tab>
        <ng-template md-tab-label>
            <md-icon>description</md-icon> Content Privileges
        </ng-template>
        Content Privileges
    </md-tab>
    <md-tab>
        <ng-template md-tab-label>
            <md-icon>flash_on</md-icon> Application Privileges
        </ng-template>
        Application Privileges
    </md-tab>
</md-tab-group>
```

And here is the output of above

[image]

Tabs are not using the full width. And label icon and text is not aligned.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

For alignment Problem: I just use `vertical-align:middle;` in `md-icon` and changed div with span. Its seems working.

```
<div>
  <md-tab-group >
    <md-tab>
        <ng-template md-tab-label>
            <md-icon style="vertical-align:middle;">description</md-icon> 
            <span class="title">Content Privileges</span>
        </ng-template>
        Content Privileges
    </md-tab>
    <md-tab>
        <ng-template md-tab-label>
            <md-icon style="vertical-align:middle;">flash_on</md-icon>
            <span class="title">Application Privileges</span>
        </ng-template>
        Application Privileges
    </md-tab>
  </md-tab-group>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use `mat-stretch-tabs` with `<mat-tab-group>` for getting equal width.
e.g-

```
<mat-tab-group mat-stretch-tabs>
  <mat-tab>
   ...
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab>
    ...
  </mat-tab >
</mat-tab-group>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use following css to spread them evenly.

```
/deep/ .mat-tab-label {
    width: 50%;
}
```

[demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/9gMN8jrpVwItULmafGGn?p=preview)

Comment: what if there are more than two tabs?

Comment: and how to align icon and text?

Comment: I see the icon text part, I'll put it in the answer, Let me know about the color.

Comment: the color of what ?

Comment: I have defined width:50%. And now If I add more tabs size is divided equally for each tab? why so?

Comment: I read your comment wrong, sorry about the 'color' question. I also checked multiple tabs, they automatically resize to evenly distributed width once set to 50%. 
Plunker is down right now, so can't work on the icon-text align fix. Once, I have something working, I'll update the answer.

Comment: Just use `md-stretch-tabs` attribute on `md-tab-group`.

Comment: @Edric!! Thanks, This is working. but I read the whole documentation, did not find this. where you find that :P

Comment: @SunilGarg It's not on the docs :(, I found it in the [`demo-app` source code for tabs](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/demo-app/tabs/tabs-demo.html#L197-L204)

Comment: And by the way, it won't work with `<nav md-nav-tabs>`.